# Mnesia in 2 separate IEx sessions on the same node

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

I'm learning Erlang's mnesia DB and trying to use it in Elixir app. According to documentation while creating a schema by default mnesia creates a directory with the name "Mnesia.#{node}". Here is the code for mnesia preparation:

```
:mnesia.create_schema([node])
:mnesia.start
:mnesia.create_table(User,
  [
    attributes: [:name, :email],
    disc_copies: [node]
  ]
)
```

When I'm starting 2 separate IEx sessions and make some transactional queries it seems they are only happened in one of the session. I infer this from :mnesia.info output.

How can I synchronise them, or is it an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one starts a shell without an explicitly specified node name, it’s started as `nonode@nohost`:

```
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source-e7be63d] ...
Interactive Elixir (1.5.0-dev) ...

iex(1)> node()
:nonode@nohost
```

`Mnesia` itself is node-aware. So, you need to explicitly remote-connect to the node, that is aware of running `mnesia`. Let’s start a named shell:

```
$ iex --sname mnesia # the node name is arbitrary
iex(mnesia@localhost)1>
```

Now, let’s start the second shell *and connect to the firstly started shell remotely*. To do so, just start a shell, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to enter `User switch command` mode and type:

```
User switch command
--> r 'mnesia@localhost' 'Elixir.IEx'
--> c
```

Now you have two shells, connected to the same node, that handles a `mnesia` instance.

More info in [the IEx docs on remote shells](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-remote-shells).

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that and it seems to work. But if the default node is `:nonode@nohost`, shouldn't both IEx sessions connect to the same mnesia instance?

Comment: nonode@nohost is kinda none, like NULL in SQL. They are not a named nodes.